# How to bind wlan and tun

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, network-interface

When you want to 'bind' eth and wlan on your computer, you use `ip_forwarding` set to 1.

How do you do to 'route/bind' such a configuration to access VPN server **from** `wlan` , through `eth`?

**anna client<-->wifi (wlan:13.37.42.1) [computer] eth0 <--  V P N --> server 3.1.170.110**

Currently it does not work. What happens: Anna pings and get :

- ping 13.37.42.1 => ok
- ping 3.1.170.110 => ok
- ping 8.8.8.8 => fail (GoogleDNS)
- ping anydomain.any => fail (indeed, since DNS unreachable)
- ping anyotherIP=> fail

  ---

____ ROUTE when VPN is **on** :

```
Destination     Passerelle      Genmask         Indic Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.8.0.77       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.1        10.8.0.77       255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.77       *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
13.37.42.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
ns350510.ip-3-1  192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.77       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

___ ROUTE when VPN is **off**

```
Destination     Passerelle      Genmask         Indic Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
13.37.42.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

__ IPtables of the computer (which offers WIFI AP and is linked to VPN server):

```
 # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 
    *mangle
    :PREROUTING ACCEPT [7471:1066114]
    :INPUT ACCEPT [5960:830272]
    :FORWARD ACCEPT [1339:216774]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [717:92366]
    :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2116:318321]
    :internet - [0:0]
    -A PREROUTING -j internet
    -A internet -m mac --mac-source 60:F8:4D:BE:43:AE -j RETURN
    -A internet -j MARK --set-xmark 0x3e7/0xffffffff
    COMMIT
    # Completed 
    # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 
    *nat
    :PREROUTING ACCEPT [1710:298954]
    :INPUT ACCEPT [1480:280336]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [28:4162]
    :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [86:6162]
    -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m mark --mark 0x3e7 -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 13.37.42.1:80
    -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m mark --mark 0x3e7 -m tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DNAT --to-destination 13.37.42.1:80
    -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
    -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
    COMMIT
    # Completed 
    # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 
    *filter
    :INPUT ACCEPT [6041:840617]
    :FORWARD ACCEPT [380:110945]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [753:102159]
    -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -j ACCEPT
    COMMIT
    # Completed
```

Comment: Pls see my Edit.

Answer (score 2):

You do not really `bind` `eth0` and `tun0` any more than you bind `wlan0` and `tun0`. You actually allow the the packets to pass from one interface to another, by setting `ip_forwarding=1`, either permanently by changing `/etc/sysctl.conf`, or temporarily by  `echo`-ing 1 into `/proc/sys/kernel/net/ipv4/ip_forward`.

The only thing that is missing is the change of packet header: if you simply let them through  as they stand, the packets will carry as the IP of origin that of the issuing pc, which is not that of the interface thru which they exited your system (`wlan0`, in this case). So you need `iptables` to make them look like they originated from `wlan0`, for them to find the way back home. `iptables` takes care automatically of remembering which connection has to be routed back to `tun0`, and which connection doesn't need to be:

```
       iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

EDIT:

you are trying to keep your pc connected simultaneously with your `eth0` and `wlan0`. The instructions I gave you assume you are **only** connected via `wlan0`. You should disconnect from the ethernet, restart openvpn, and check that they do work indeed.

Keeping both `eth0` and `wlan0` connected simultaneously, starting an instance of OpenVPN on `wlan0` and routing LAN traffic from `tun0` via the OpenVPN **can** be done, but requires a different technique. I suggest you ask a different question about this.

Comment: Thank you. (you missed `-t nat` btw). No need to do the same with `tun0` ?

Comment: Thanks, I corrected that. No, you only need to masquerade stuff from the tun0 network going into your LAN because no one else on the LAN knows where the tun0 network is. If you did not MASQUERADE the replies would be lost at your gateway.

Comment: I tried but nothing has changed. I cannot reach anything but the VPN server (with its IP *and* its domain name). Strange... my wifi client can see the distant vpn server, but nothing else. I read this also but no more success, I get it work 1 time, http://bradmont.net/pi_router/#iptables-nat-masquerading:92b7a0ff94f0da31f67604bb2ffd7293

Comment: @ArchiT3K Can you please post your routing table?